# How to avoid repetition of subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I want to avoid repeatedly using subqueries. My query is as follows:

```
;WITH Temp(Ticker, FromDate, ToDate, BuyingQty, SellingQty, ABP, ASP)
AS
(
select 
Ticker,
min(trxdate) as FromDate,
max(TrxDate) as ToDate,
case buysell when 'b' then SUM(Lot) end as BuyingQty,
case buysell when 's' then SUM(Lot) end as SellingQty,
case buysell when 'b' then CAST(SUM(Lot * price)/SUM(Lot) AS Decimal(10,2)) end as ABP,
case buysell when 's' then cast(SUM(Lot * price)/SUM(Lot) AS Decimal(10,2)) end as ASP
from transaksi where SettleDate is null
group by Ticker, buysell
)
select Ticker, 
Min(FromDate) as FromDate, 
Min(ToDate) as ToDate,
DATEDIFF(day, min(FromDate), max(ToDate)) as Days, 
SUM(buyingQty) as BuyingQty, 
SUM(sellingQty) as SellingQty,
case when(sum(sellingQty) is null) then SUM(BuyingQty) else SUM(buyingQty) - SUM(sellingQty) end as BalQty,
SUM(ABP) as ABP,
SUM(ASP) as ASP,
(SUM(ASP) - SUM(ABP)) * SUM(SellingQtY) AS Profit,
cast((SUM(ASP) - SUM(ABP)) / sum(ABP) * 100 as decimal(10,2))  AS [Profit%],
(select curprice from Stock where Temp.Ticker = Stock.Ticker) AS [Cur Price],
(select curprice from Stock where Temp.Ticker = Stock.Ticker) * 
case when(sum(sellingQty) is null) then SUM(BuyingQty) else (SUM(buyingQty) - SUM(sellingQty)) end as [Cur. Value]
from Temp group by Ticker order by 1,2
```

1. Please note the I am querying `balQty` and `CurPrice` twice each. Will that affect the efficiency and how to avoid it?

   `balQty:`

   ```
     case when(sum(sellingQty) is null) 
            then SUM(BuyingQty) 
            else SUM(buyingQty) - SUM(sellingQty) 
     end
   ```

   `curprice:`

   ```
   select curprice 
   from Stock 
   where Temp.Ticker = Stock.Ticker
   ```
2. how to use variable inside CTE? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Cross Apply` to avoid repetition of `balQty` logic. You can use `left join` with `Stock` to get the `cur price`.

Using `Variable` inside CTE is same as you do it in regular query. Added a new variable `@buysell` to demonstrate that.

```
Declare @buySell varchar(1)
SET @buySell = 'a'


;WITH Temp(Ticker, FromDate, ToDate, BuyingQty, SellingQty, ABP, ASP)
AS
(
select 
Ticker,
min(trxdate) as FromDate,
max(TrxDate) as ToDate,
case buysell when 'b' then SUM(Lot) end as BuyingQty,
case buysell when 's' then SUM(Lot) end as SellingQty,
case buysell when 'b' then CAST(SUM(Lot * price)/SUM(Lot) AS Decimal(10,2)) end as ABP,
case buysell when 's' then cast(SUM(Lot * price)/SUM(Lot) AS Decimal(10,2)) end as ASP
from transaksi where SettleDate is null
and buysell = @buysell
  group by Ticker, buysell
)
select T.Ticker, 
Min(FromDate) as FromDate, 
Min(ToDate) as ToDate,
DATEDIFF(day, min(FromDate), max(ToDate)) as Days, 
SUM(buyingQty) as BuyingQty, 
SUM(sellingQty) as SellingQty,
SUM(C1.BalQty) AS BalQty,
SUM(ABP) as ABP,
SUM(ASP) as ASP,
(SUM(ASP) - SUM(ABP)) * SUM(SellingQtY) AS Profit,
cast((SUM(ASP) - SUM(ABP)) / sum(ABP) * 100 as decimal(10,2))  AS [Profit%],
SUM(S.curprice) AS [Cur Price],
SUM(S.curprice * C1.BalQty) as [Cur. Value]
from Temp T
LEFT JOIN Stock S ON T.Ticker = S.Ticker
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT  case when(T.sellingQty is null) then T.BuyingQty else T.buyingQty - T.sellingQty end AS BalQty
) C1


group by T.Ticker order by 1,2
```

**Method 2**

```
;WITH Temp(Ticker, FromDate, ToDate, BuyingQty, SellingQty, ABP, ASP)
AS
(
select 
Ticker,
min(trxdate) as FromDate,
max(TrxDate) as ToDate,
case buysell when 'b' then SUM(Lot) end as BuyingQty,
case buysell when 's' then SUM(Lot) end as SellingQty,
case buysell when 'b' then CAST(SUM(Lot * price)/SUM(Lot) AS Decimal(10,2)) end as ABP,
case buysell when 's' then cast(SUM(Lot * price)/SUM(Lot) AS Decimal(10,2)) end as ASP
from transaksi where SettleDate is null
  group by Ticker, buysell
)
,CTE2 AS
(
select T.Ticker, 
Min(FromDate) as FromDate, 
Min(ToDate) as ToDate,
DATEDIFF(day, min(FromDate), max(ToDate)) as Days, 
SUM(buyingQty) as BuyingQty, 
SUM(sellingQty) as SellingQty,
SUM(ABP) as ABP,
SUM(ASP) as ASP,
(SUM(ASP) - SUM(ABP)) * SUM(SellingQtY) AS Profit,
cast((SUM(ASP) - SUM(ABP)) / sum(ABP) * 100 as decimal(10,2))  AS [Profit%],
S.curprice AS [Cur Price],
from Temp T
LEFT JOIN Stock S ON T.Ticker = S.Ticker
group by T.Ticker order by 1,2
)

SELECT
Ticker, 
FromDate, 
ToDate,
Days, 
BuyingQty, 
SellingQty,
C1.BalQty,
ABP,
ASP,
Profit,
[Profit%],
[Cur Price],
[Cur Price]*C1.BalQty AS [Cur Val]
FROM CTE2 T
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT  case when(T.sellingQty is null) then T.BuyingQty else T.buyingQty - T.sellingQty end AS BalQty
) C1
```

Comment: Thank you. Left join caused an error : Msg 4101, Level 15, State 1, Line 33 Aggregates on the right side of an APPLY cannot reference columns from the left side.

Comment: Move the left join before cross apply and try to see if that works. Updated the answer. 
Also does your original query runs fine?

Comment: Is that possible to assign a subquery result to a variable and use it for further computation inside CTE?

Comment: Made another change. Check and see if that works ok. Also working on another version. Test the updated one and let me know if that works.

Comment: Added another update to Method 1 and added method 2. Test both.

Comment: There are some problem about ambiguous column name 'Ticker' and C1.balQty not contained in aggregate function, but that is ok and I can adjust it, only the query result is empty now.

Comment: make sure you remove the @buysell variable. Becuase it filters by 'a'. you dont have any such records.

Comment: Method 2 works ok, thank you very much for your help!